# How to see that $h$ defined in this way is primitive recursive?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, computability, recursion

I am trying to understand the proof here:

[How to prove that this function is primitive recursive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85712/how-to-prove-that-this-function-is-primitive-recursive)

In the answer below, $f,\pi,g$ are primitive recursive. $P,G,h$ are defined in the way below:
$$
  \begin{align}
  P(n,x,0)&=x\\ P(n,x,i+1)&=\pi(n-(i+1),P(n,x,i)) \\
  G(n,x,0)&=f(P(n,x,n)) \\ G(n,x,i+1)&=g(i,P(n,x,n-(i+1)),G(n,x,i)) \\
  h(n,x) &= G(n,x,n) \\
  \end{align}
$$

I need to prove that $h$ is indeed primitive recursive. Here is my definition of primitive recursive:[image]

And we can obtain recursive function by composition, as this picture mentions that it can be obtained by substitution:
[image]

So to prove that $h$ is primitive recursive, it  is sufficient to prove $G$ is primitive recursive. But $G$ seems not to be a **total** function, and thus seems cannot be primitive recursive. For instance, it is not defined at $n=0,i+1=1$.

I am confused. So may I please ask if $G$ and $P$ are primitive recursive? How can I see this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is: what is the definition of subtraction? It's not uncommon in this context to define subtraction such that it produces $0$ when it would "normally" be negative. This produces a total function $\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @DerekElkins So in this way that subtraction is defined, is it remains can be called as primitive recursive?

Comment: Sure. Subtraction, in the sense I gave, is trivially definable with primitive recursion. With subtraction being primitively recursive, $P$ is clearly of the form appropriate for primitive recursion, just define $h(i,z,y) = \pi(\pi_{2,1}(y)-(i+1),z)$ which is a composition of primitive recursive functions and $g(y) = \pi_{2,2}(y)$. So $P$ is primitive recursive, and $G$ is then also clearly of the appropriate form for primitive recursion. In fact, even if you don't take as given that $x\mapsto f(x,x)$ is primitive recursive if $f$ is, you can prove it with the axioms in your question.